# Change Variables data with each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok let me just change the whole thing and show exactly what i want my output to be, sorry for bad explanation.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-custom table-striped"> 
    <% 0.upto(years).each do |n| %>
      <% @value = (((price*quantity)*percentage)/100)+(quantity*price) %>
      <tr>
        <td width="20%"><%= n %></td>
        <td width="20%"><%= ((@value*percentage)/100)+@value %></td> 
      </tr>
    <% end %> 
</table>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to set @value variable to new value taken from one calucated in that loop.

My output atm looks something like this:

```
0   @value

1   @value

2   @value
```

But i want to it to look like this:

```
0   @value

1   new_value calculated from ((@value*percentage)/100)+@value

2   new_value2 calculated from ((new_value*percentage)/100)+new_value
```

I know this still looks like nonsense, but i hope i tried to explain this time what im trying to do ;p

Thanks.

Comment: can you clarify what your expect output is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-custom table-striped">
  <% @value = price * quantity %> 
  <% 0.upto(years).each do |n| %>
    <% @value += ((@value * percentage)) / 100 %>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><%= n %></td>
      <td width="20%"><%= @value %></td> 
    </tr>
  <% end %> 
</table>
```

This will give you the increase (or decrease) in price when a constant percentage is added every year.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works exactly as i wanted, only had to change += to =, needed to print new @value not @value+old@value, but u made my day, thanks !:D

Comment: woops, that was a mistake on my part!

Answer (score 0):

In ruby you can print a variable with `print variable` (it won't add a new line at the end) or you can use puts to add a new line `puts variable`. If you're trying to concatenate strings you can `print "#{var1} and #{var2}"`.

checkout
http://tryruby.org

https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-ruby

Answer (score 0):

use reduce instead of each do accumulate the intermedia value.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-custom table-striped">
  <% 0.upto(years).reduce(price * quantity) do |value, n| %>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><%= n %></td>
      <td width="20%"><%= value %></td> 
    </tr>
    <% value += ((value * percentage)) / 100 %>
  <% end %> 
</table>
```